# How to put a warped image on top of another using Python PIL?

Tags: python, django, image, api, python-imaging-library

Here's an example:

(you can test it as a site user in the URL below)

https://placeit.net/c/mockups/stages/t-shirt-mockup-of-a-cool-man-posing-in-a-dark-alley-2357-el1?iref=apparel-mockups-best-sellers-output

User will upload an image and it will be applied as tshirt design on the mockup.

I am not expecting to be able to develop a mega website such as Placeit but I would like to learn if similar to this very webpage in the url above.

My initial idea is to use PIL lib of Python and then Django.

If not, could you give me Python libraries that are more suitable? or other workaround?

I understood that it includes atleast 2 images.

First image is the tshirt with guy that I can do in photoshop with transparent layer on the shirt part along with shadows to make it look realistic (the folds in the shirt).

Second image is the user's uploaded image.

And yeah, the combining of two image is what I would like to know, esp the warped part.

Tried PIL in combining the 2 images but it is only one on top of another, the warped part is the hard part. I guess its not only PIL but no idea which API or library to use.